# Maximum Length parallel line

Tags: qgis, length, parallel-lines

[image]I have a polygon and I want to make parallel lines inside of the polygon. I need to have the maximum length when I sum the length of all of them.
Each line must be 15 m apart.

[image: Polygon that I want to make the parallel lines]

Answer (score 4):

I tested few options for fixed interval between lines:

- Medial axis
- Minimum bounding rectangle
- Centre of largest inscribed radius
- Boundary buffers

[image]

Last one stands out because it beats others by in accounting of polygon shape. So, use it if stepping back a little from the boundary is an option.